# React and momentjs - check two array of dates and returns boolean

Tags: reactjs, momentjs

I have this calendar component and `handleDayPickerChange` handles the selection of days on the calendar. In the code below, there's

```
const today = moment();

type SelectDate = SELECT_DATE.START | SELECT_DATE.END;

type DayDataSource = {
  date: string,
  bookable: boolean,
};

type Props = {
  onSubmit: () => mixed,
  spaceId: string,
  minimumDuration: number,
  client: ApolloClient<any>,
  days: Array<DayDataSource>,
};

type State = {
  month: moment,
  selectDate: ?SelectDate,
};

const GET_SELECTED_DATES = gql`
  {
    selectedDates @client {
      startOn
      endOn
    }
  }
`;


class Calendar extends Component<Props, State> {
  state = {
    month: today,
    selectDate: null,
  };

  handleStartDateClick = () => {
    this.setState({ selectDate: SELECT_DATE.START });
  };

  handleEndDateClick = () => {
    this.setState({ selectDate: SELECT_DATE.END });
  };

  handleDayPickerChange = async (e, startDate, endDate) => {
    console.log("changing");
    if (startDate && endDate ) {
      return this.handleDateSubmit(startDate, endDate);
    } else {
      const newDates = convertDatesToPeriodAttribute({ endOn: endDate, startOn: startDate });
      //write the selectedDates
      await this.props.client.writeData({
        data: {
          selectedDates: newDates,
        },
      });
      startDate ? this.setState({ selectDate: SELECT_DATE.END }) : this.setState({ selectDate: SELECT_DATE.START });
    }
  };

  handleDateSubmit = async (startDate, endDate) => {
    await this.props.client.writeData({
      data: {
        selectedDates: convertDatesToPeriodAttribute({ endOn: endDate, startOn: startDate }),
      },
    });

    this.setState({ selectDate: null });
  };

  handleDayPickerClose = () => {
    this.setState({
      selectDate: null,
    });
  };

  handleClearDates = (startDate, endDate) => () => {
    if (startDate || endDate) {
      this.props.client.writeData({
        data: {
          selectedDates: [],
        },
      });

      this.setState(() => ({
        selectDate: SELECT_DATE.START,
      }));
    } else {
      this.handleDayPickerClose();
    }
  };


  handleMonthChange = (e, month) => {
    this.setState({ month });
  };

  calculateBookingLength = (startDate, endDate): number => {
    return startDate && endDate ? endDate.diff(startDate, 'days') + 1 : 0 
  };

  render() {
    const { month, selectDate } = this.state;
    const { onSubmit, spaceId, minimumDuration, days } = this.props;

    return (
      <Query query={GET_SELECTED_DATES}>
        {({ data: { selectedDates }, loading, error}) => {
          if (loading) return null;
          if (error) return null;

          const selectedDatesMoment = convertDatesToMomentLocal(selectedDates);
          const startDate = selectedDatesMoment.length ? selectedDatesMoment[0].startOn : null;
          const endDate = selectedDatesMoment.length ? selectedDatesMoment[0].endOn : null;
          const bookingLength = this.calculateBookingLength(startDate, endDate);
          const validSelection = isSelectionValid({
            selectedDates: [{startOn: startDate, endOn:endDate}],
            minimumDurationInDays: minimumDuration,
            sparse: false,
          });

          return (
            <div>
              <div className={css.section} data-testid="simplified-calendar">
                <div className={css.datesHeadline}>{'Dates'}</div>
                <div
                  className={cx(
                    css.dayRangeContainer,
                    selectDate ? css.dayRangeContainerActive : null,
                  )}
                >
                  <DurationDropdownTarget
                    className={cx(
                      css.dayPickerTarget,
                      selectDate ? css.dayPickerTargetActive : null,
                    )}
                    iconVisibilityClass={css.iconVisible}
                    startDate={startDate}
                    endDate={endDate}
                    id="tenancyDuration"
                    selectDate={selectDate}
                    onStartDateClick={this.handleStartDateClick}
                    onEndDateClick={this.handleEndDateClick}
                    onClearDatesClick={this.handleClearDates(startDate, endDate)}
                    active={!!selectDate}
                  />
                </div>
                {selectDate && (
                  <div className={css.datePickerContainer}>
                    <DayRangePicker
                      month={month}
                      selectDate={selectDate}
                      startDate={startDate}
                      endDate={endDate}
                      onInteraction={this.handleDayPickerChange}
                      onMonthChange={this.handleMonthChange}
                      isDisabled={(d) => d.isBefore(today, 'day') || days.find(day => day.date === d.format('YYYY-MM-DD') && !day.bookable)}
                      classNames={{header: 'fs-ignore-rage-clicks'}}
                    />
                  </div>
                )}
              </div>
              {validSelection && (
                <div className={css.section}>
                  <Recap simplifiedCalendarEnabled={true} spaceId={spaceId} sparse={false} showDeposit={false} />
                </div>
              )}
              {(bookingLength < minimumDuration && bookingLength > 0) && (
                <div className={css.section}>
                  <MinimumDurationNotification minimumDuration={minimumDuration} />
                </div>
              )}
              <div className={css.section}>
                <BookingButtonContainer
                  className={css.submitButton}
                  spaceId={spaceId}
                  disabled={!validSelection}
                  onClick={onSubmit}
                />
              </div>
            </div>
          );
        }}
      </Query>
    );
  }
}

export default withApollo(Calendar);
```

Now I want to do something where it checks if the dates in between startDate and endDate has any unavailable dates - then it will return false. So something like..

```
checkIfSelectionIsGood = (startDate, endDate) => {
//check days from startDate to endDate against days prop..
//return true or false

}
```

How should I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this using [getTime()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gettime.asp),

```
checkIfSelectionIsGood = (startDate, endDate) => {
//check days from startDate to endDate against days prop..
//return true or false

let startDate = new Date(startDate).getTime();
let endDate = new Date(endDate).getTime();

//Assuming `this.props.days` is array
this.props.days.map((day)=>{
   let day = new Date(day).getTime();
   if(day>=startDate && day<=endDate){
      return true;
   }else{
      return false;
   }
})

}
```